# Does the Lie algebra of vector fields $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ determine the diffeomorphism class of a manifold $M$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M_1,M_2$ be two simply connected, connected, compact smooth  manifolds without boundary and of the same dimension. Assume that $\mathfrak{X}(M_1)\cong \mathfrak{X}(M_2)$ as Lie algebras.

> **Question.** Are $M_1$ and $M_2$ diffeomorphic?

This seems like a basic question but I did not find anything on Google.

Comment: For some context I can say that (abstract) diffeomorphism group determines compact manifold uniquely; of course, this has only very *tangential* relation to the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is *yes*, and the assumptions "simply connected" and "compact" are actually unnecessary.

In fact, it is possible to reconstruct any smooth manifold $M$, up to diffeomorphisms, by using the subalgebra $\mathfrak{X}_0(M)$ of vector fields with compact support. See

*Shanks, M. E.; Pursell, Lyle E.*, [**The Lie algebra of a smooth manifold**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2031961), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 5, 468-472 (1954). [ZBL0055.42105](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0055.42105), [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2031961#metadata_info_tab_contents).

Comment: Can we reconstruct differentiable maps from maps of Lie algebras, or is this passing to Lie algebras fully faithful?

Comment: Surely, a isomorphism $\Phi$ of Lie Algebras (of vector fields) induces a diffeomorphism $\varphi$ between the two manifolds such that $\Phi = d \varphi$.

Comment: I am asking slightly more generally – any maps, instead of isomorphisms.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I do not know, I should check the proof.

Comment: @Z. M: It's not a functor, so it's not clear what your question would mean.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie Thanks, I was confused. It is not functorial.